Demonstrate the left side of a differential equation equals the right side of that differential equation in the frequency domain (MATLAB numerically)
For the differential equation
$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+7.25*\frac{dx}{dt}-4x=10.25*\sin{(2\pi8t)}+5.89*\sin{(2\pi13t)}-13.94*\sin{(2\pi17t)}$
demonstrate numerically that the frequency domain representation of the left side equals the frequency domain representation of the right side (how is the MATLAB code snippet wrong?).
The MATLAB code below demonstrates the system's output and 1st/2nd derivatives in the frequency domain given the identified forcing function.

Here is the left side and right side of the differential equation in the frequency domain.  You can see they aren't equal.  They are almost equal at the forcing function's harmonics but, even there, not quite.

This is the MATLAB code from which the plots are generated.  What am I doing wrong?
% SOLVE d2x/dt2+7.25* dx/dt - 4 x = 10.25*sin(2*pi*f(1)*t)+5.89*sin(2*pi*(f(2))*t)-13.94*sin(2*pi*(f(3))*t)
% freq= [8 13 17];
% initial conditions: x(0) = 0, x'(0)=0

format longG;

a=0;
b=4*pi*0.3183;
N=4096; 
dx=(b-a)/N;
t = a + dx * (0:N-1)';

fs=1/dx;

freq= [8 13 17];

%Find the system Response
initial_x = 0;
initial_dxdt = 0;
[t,x]=ode45( @rhs, t, [initial_x initial_dxdt] );

%Plot the system response
figure;
plot(t,x(:,1));
xlabel('t'); ylabel('x');
title("Forcing Function");

%Get a frequency vector 
k=2*pi/(b-a)*[0:N/2-1,0,-N/2+1:-1]'; %the middle zero kills the constant term

%Calculate and plot the frequency domain of the system response
subplot(3,1,1);
%fftx=fft(lowpass(x(:,1),400,fs,'Steepness',0.55));
fftx = fft(x(:,1));
%plot(k([2050:end-1,1:2048]),fftx([2050:end-1,1:2048]));
plot(k([end-100:end,1:100]),abs(10*log10(fftx([end-100:end,1:100])).^2/N));
title("Frequency Domain of System Response X(t)");

%First derivative of system response in frequency domain
dffft = 1i*k.*fftx;
subplot(3,1,2); plot(k([end-100:end,1:100]),10*log10(abs(dffft([end-100:end,1:100])).^2/N));title("Frequency Domain: First Derivative of X(t)");

%Second derivative of system response in frequency domain
d2ffft = 1i*k.*dffft;
subplot(3,1,3); plot(k([end-100:end,1:100]),10*log10(abs(d2ffft([end-100:end,1:100])).^2/N));title("Frequency Domain: Second Derivative of X(t)");

%Calculate the left side of the differential equation in the frequency
%domain
leftside = d2ffft([end-100:end,1:100])+7.25*dffft([end-100:end,1:100])-4*fftx([end-100:end,1:100]);


%Plot the left side vs the right side in the frequency domain

%plot the leftside
figure;
plot(k([end-100:end,1:100]),10*log10(abs(leftside).^2/N));

%Get the frequency domain representation of the forcing function (i.e. the
%right side of the differential equation)
dfft_forcing = fft(forcingF(t));

%Plot the right side
hold on;
plot(k([end-100:end,1:100]),10*log10(abs(dfft_forcing([end-100:end,1:100])).^2/N));

legend("left side","right side");;
title("Differential Equation's Left Side vs. Right Side");

function dxdt=rhs(t,x)
    dxdt_1 = x(2);
    dxdt_2 = -7.25*x(2) + 4*x(1) + forcingF(t);
    dxdt=[dxdt_1; dxdt_2];
end

function [ff]=forcingF(t) 
    f= [8 13 17];
    ff = 10.25*sin(2*pi*f(1)*t)+5.89*sin(2*pi*(f(2))*t)-13.94*sin(2*pi*(f(3))*t);
end


It looks like the second derivative is blowing things up.  But I have tried low pass filtering the system response with no real change.

Your main problem is the response of $x[t]$: It is growing exponentially (see figure below), and indeed if you analyse your differential equation, you'll find its response is unstable (in the Laplace domain, you'll find one of the poles is in the right half plane). This is causing your analysis approach to not give the results you hope.
The analysis approach you're trying to use will only work with the steady state response, if the response is stable. Therefore, even if the response was stable, you'd still have to ignore all data prior to the transient response sufficiently decaying.
The steady state response must dominate because the discrete Fourier transform assumes your signal is periodic. In your case, the trend of $x[t]$ almost resembles a ramp, and therefore from the discrete Fourier transform's perspective, it looks like a sawtooth wave, which you'll find closely matches the fft of your $x[nT]$ vector. Moreover, it then follows that using the Fourier transform derivative relationships essentially gives you the derivatives of that sawtooth wave.

As a solution, compute the left-hand side in the discrete time domain, and then compute the fft of that. Here is some Matlab example code to replace your computation of leftside:
leftside = fft(filter([1,-2,1]/dx^2 + 7.25*[1,0,-1]/2/dx - 4*[0,1,0],1,x(:,1)));
leftside = leftside([end-100:end,1:100]);

After making this change, I got the following plot, which is a significant improvement:


Thanks.  It seems by changing the system's equation so that it is stable, I get good results: $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+7.25*\frac{dx}{dt}+4x=10.25*\sin{(2\pi8t)}+5.89*\sin{(2\pi13t)}-13.94*\sin{(2\pi17t)}$
